# Kinetic energy relationships with momentum and mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum

If I have some arbitrary particle, we will call particle 1 and another particle 2 that have the same momentum, yet particle 1 has half the mass of particle 2, how does the kinetic energy compare between the two particles?

I guess I am looking for a ratio K2/K1. I can't seem to think it through.

Answer (score 2):

You can write kinetic energy as 
$$K=\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{mv^2}{2}=\frac{(mv)^2}{2m}.$$

You can take the next few steps of rewriting this in terms of momentum $p=mv$.

Answer (score 1):

Try showing that the kinetic energy of a particle of mass $m$ and momentum $\vec { p } $ can be written as $$K=\frac{p^2}{2m}$$
The solution to your problem should be clear from there. This expression for kinetic energy is actually a pretty handy formula to have memorized.

Answer (score 0):

Your particles have the same momentum, so one has twice the velocity of the other. Their KE is in the ratio $$\frac{\left( \frac{m}{2}v^{2} \right)}{m\left( \frac{v}{2} \right)^{2}}=2$$

It gets confusing because energy is not conserved as a particular form. Once you get a handle on the work-energy theorem or the relationship of work and energy many things become clear, like why a car can not accelerate as quickly at 80 mph as at 0.